# BottomSheetBehavior padding

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, bottom-sheet

I have such kind of fragment layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBlack">

    <MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/vBottomSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For my `vBottomSlider` I create a `BottomSheetBehavior` instance:

```
val bh = BottomSheetBehavior.from(vBottomSlider)
bh.isHideable = false
bh.peekHeight = 50.dpToPx
bh.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomCallback)
```

That's all inside the fragment.

My main activity layout looks like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/vMainConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/vNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For my `fContent` i set bottom `padding` as `vNavigation` height. When i scroll down my `vBottomSlider`, i hide `vNavigation` by changing its `translationY`, and set `padding` for my `fContent` (by taking `onSlide` event from `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback`).

Sliding with finger completely, works fine.
But when i `fling` or set `EXPANDED` or `COLLAPSED` state programmatically for my `BottomSheetBehavior` instance its not get scrolled completely. Here is always some space (it seems to be height of my `vNavigation`).

Answer (score -6):

I've managed to resolve this by editing the source of `BottomSheetBehavior`.
My solution is little hacky. Send e-mail if you need edited class.

Comment: post solution here, do not need ask for send email :)

Comment: @Tim, it's too large